# In webdriver what are the essential attribute(s) that checkbox must have to check that check box is check or seleted

Tags: java, html, webdriver

I have the below outer html for a check box.

Line

So how do I add a code to veirfy it is checked  since it doesn't have any attribute as 
checked="checked"
ng-checked="false"

I was thinking application devlopment team should add an attribute to make sure it's a checkbox .

I think I can get xpath as

```
//input[@id="777"]/following-sibling::label

    boolean isChecked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id="777"]/following-sibling::label"));

    if (isChecked = false) {
        check the box;
    } else {
        do nothing;
    }
```

Comment: you must find your input with id from `for`. checked is set on input not on label, label just say for which input to check.

Comment: This element don't have ID's , just the label . So it won't be an option .

Comment: @SameeraDeSilva : probably this is not the element which is responsible for the visual check box, please check siblings and provide more detailed source

Comment: @TharakaDeshan the outter hitml is added in quetion so using //input[@id="777"]/following-sibling::label[1] I can able to locate the elemnet  even though there are four items on the list .